# How to specify mimetype of files with no extension in NGINX config?

Tags: nginx, mime-types

I have a server with nginx. And I have a lot of images - pngs and jpgs saved as files with no extension (like "123123123_321312").

When I use tag "img" in html page, I get theese messages in console:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://xxxx/images/1350808948_997628". jquery.js:2
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://xxxx/images/1343808569_937350".
```

Is there a way to make nginx add header with correct mimetype of the requested file?

Comment: Ok, probably nginx cannot auto send mime headers depend on file actual contents.
So the only way to remove those errors is as Demikl said - use JPEG-mimeheader always.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the [`default_type`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#default_type) directive :

```
server {
   ...
   default_type text/html;

   location /images/png {
      default_type image/png;
   }

   location /images/jpg {
      default_type image/jpeg;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would be the solution if files where in different folders.
But in my case I have all the files in one place.

Comment: It seems that specifying the MIME-type `image/jpeg` even if the actual file is a PNG image does not generate any warning logs. Just tested with Google Chrome.

Comment: In case anyone else got confused by this (like I did), be sure to do a full refresh in your browser after setting default_type and reloading the nginx configuration. Either clear the cache, or shift-F5 in Chrome, otherwise the browser will get a 304 and assume the original content type is still valid.

Answer (score -1):

I also have to add.

Mickaël Le Baillif solution also works if your web page is downloaded instead of executed. 
Because nginx thinks that it should be `default_type application/octet-stream;` even though the official documentation says:

> To make a particular location emit the “application/octet-stream” MIME
>   type for all requests, the following configuration can be used

And points to `location /download/` 
This also gives:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://xxxxx.com/"
```

Nginx version: 1.6.2