# How to serve extensionless files as text/html using Express?

Tags: azure, express, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Express to serve a static website using Nginx. Many of the files have no extension and the contents are HTML. When they are served, the MIME type is application/octet-stream. How do I serve any extensionless files as text/html?

EDIT: I am doing this in an Azure App Service on Linux, so I don't have full control of the server. I can't just go create the `/etc/nginx/mime.types` file and expect it to work due to the nature of a managed web service. I did, however, create that file to see if it fixed my issue in the short term, and it did not. I created `/etc/nginx/mime.types` and added as the contents...

```
server {
   default_type text/html;
}
```

I then restarted the server, but I still get `application/octet-stream`.

I was hoping there was a way to do this in Express. Here's the Node code I'm using to serve my static site...

```
var express = require('express');
express()
    .use(express.static(__dirname))
    .listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

I attempted to add `express.static.mime.define({'text/html': ['']});` after the `var express...` line, but that didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force nginx to send specific Content-Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629930/force-nginx-to-send-specific-content-type)

Comment: Could also be a duplicate of [How to specify mimetype of files with no extension in NGINX config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509050/how-to-specify-mimetype-of-files-with-no-extension-in-nginx-config)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally!

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path')

express()
  .use(express.static(__dirname, {
    setHeaders: (res, requestPath) => {
      let noExtension = !Boolean(path.extname(requestPath));
      if(noExtension) res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    }
  }))

  .listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```